# Error in ifelse(new_lf$State %in% c("01", "02", "04", "05", "12", "13", : argument "yes" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to create the dummies for my data, the data I have is for 50 states in America and I want to set 25 states' dummy equals to 1 and the other 25 states' dummy equal 0, the code below is that I have now

```
project_path <- "C:/Users/85384/Desktop/Capstone" 
setwd(project_path)
lf <- read_excel("Labor force data by county.xlsx")
new_lf <- na.omit(lf)
names(new_lf)[names(new_lf) == 'Column1'] <- 'LAUS_Area_Code'
names(new_lf)[names(new_lf) == 'Column2'] <- 'State'
names(new_lf)[names(new_lf) == 'Column3'] <- 'County'
names(new_lf)[names(new_lf) == 'Column4'] <- 'Area_Title'
names(new_lf)[names(new_lf) == 'Column5'] <- 'Period'
names(new_lf)[names(new_lf) == 'Column6'] <- 'Civilian_Labor_Force'
names(new_lf)[names(new_lf) == 'Column7'] <- 'Employed'
names(new_lf)[names(new_lf) == 'Column8'] <- 'Unemployed_level'
names(new_lf)[names(new_lf) == 'Column9'] <- 'Unemployed_rate'
View(new_lf)
is.data.frame(new_lf)
is.numeric(new_lf)

new_lf$early <- ifelse(new_lf$State %in% 
c('01','02','04','05','12','13','16','18','19',
'24','28','29','30','31','33','38','39','40', 
'46','45','47','48','49','54','56',1,0))
```

And I got
"Error in ifelse(new_lf$State %in% c("01", "02", "04", "05", "12", "13",  :
argument "yes" is missing, with no default".
By the way, my dataset is a data frame but it's not numeric, I tried to make both data frame and numeric, but it did not work, that is why I put the numbers in quotations, and the numbers in quotations are represented as state FIPS code.

Answer (score 1):

You simply made a typo. It should be

```r
new_lf$early <- ifelse(new_lf$State %in% 
c('01','02','04','05','12','13','16','18','19',
'24','28','29','30','31','33','38','39','40', 
'46','45','47','48','49','54','56'),1,0)
```

Note the placement of the parentheses.

Comment: omg, thank you! I made a stupid error lol